# Container View pushing to Detail View for Android

Tags: android

I mainly have experience with iOS app development but have decided to try my hand at an android version. What I am looking to do is a container view which pushes to a detail view including picture title and then on occasion have that push to a second example view. I would also like gesture recognition in there to swipe between pictures.

I'm sure this is possible on android but I don't know how. Please can someone put me straight on if this is in fact possible? And if so how it's done!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a very broad "question". It definitely sounds possible. Give it a shot.

Comment: Yea sorry about that, I'm almost certain it's possible, I don't have an android phone and haven't ever used one properly to see what they have as their photo gallery but I'm sure it's probably just what I'm looking for. It's more the how do I do it that's the question as it's not known as a container view as far as I can see when it's on android.

Comment: You need to read through the Android docs. There's a lot to learn. That's why I said this is too broad. You're asking a lot of different things. When you create a new Android project, there's a master detail flow template that you may find useful. Also, the `ViewPager` class will be useful for swiping. As I said, give it a try and then ask a more focused question if you're having trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.

gesture tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html

Maybe you would use `ViewPager`:
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

There are plenty of tutorials on the web, just search smartly.